# SSH login with no authentication

Tags: linux, ssh, password, user-accounts

I have an account (`root`, if it makes a difference) set up without a password (`passwd -d`), which enables me to log in with no authentication through the console. SSH however insists on a password.

How can I set up an SSH connection without authentication?

(I know what I’m doing, there’s no need to point out security considerations.)

The system in question is an Ubuntu 14.04 Server edition.

Comment: Use keys instead?

Comment: You use public/private keys without passwords. Still not ideal (you could use ssh-agent to keep track of the key's passphrase), but I'm afraid we do have to point out the security issues of passwordless accounts.

Comment: No, I don’t want to use keys.

Comment: ssh-keygen.
ssh-copy-id user@host once. Then ssh without prompt for password.

Comment: Then try to configure sshd server with following:
     PermitEmptyPasswords
             When password authentication is allowed, it specifies whether the server allows login to accounts with empty password strings.  The default is “no”.

Comment: @Navern thanks, why not an answer? Also, please see my comments at Blake R’s.

Comment: @JoóÁdám, didn't wanted to write much explanation:) Just leading advice. Still very broad question.  Of course you should update password for root with "passwd root" and provide "" string.

Comment: As for the downvoters: I would like to see some justification how is my question “not showing any research effort; is not being clear or not being useful”. @NathanC, Magellan, John, SvW, EEAA: care to elaborate how is the question off-topic?

Comment: Actually it looks like you are trying to solve some task with a wrong approach. It's not clear why key auth isn't suits you because it solves this task very well. And still.

Comment: I could use keys, but there's no need for authentication in the specific situation, so why bother. It’s just unnecessary added complexity (even if it is minor).

Comment: I think its not suited because for serverfault because it's a very specific question. But I am searching for the solution of it too. It takes 1 minute to ssh to my old RPi, and I use it only on my private network for GPIO development purposes.

Answer (score 5):

Change the PermitEmptyPasswords property from no to yes, and make sure the PermitRootLogin property is also "yes"

Comment: I have done so, but it still does not let me in. (`PermitRootLogin` was already set, and I’m able to log in by setting a password. sshd was restarted.) Do you have any idea what further steps should I take?

Comment: Note: I have added some system details to the question.